# Vestax SPIN & Algoriddim Djay - Streaming online

Tags: software, plugins

I am using Algoriddim djay with a midi controller (Vestax spin). When I am mixing I can route the output audio and the monitoring (pre-cueing) output on my controller, it works fine.

However, when I want to stream online (on ustream.tv) with audio hijack pro and sound flower I can hear the main output through my computer and I cannot hear sound from the pre-cueing output I set before. The audio configuration has not changed in Algoriddim Djay and as soon as I stop "hijacking" the sound in audio hijack I can hear my from my monitoring channel again.

I was able to mix before with the same settings, I do not know why it is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it without audio hijack pro thanks to this: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/1094/redirect-audio-output-from-a-streaming-app-to-a-dj-app. I just used soundflower. I set my master output to "Soundflower Ch 2" in Algoriddim Djay, I set my Soundflower 2ch output to "SPIN" and I set "Soundflower Ch 2" as my input in Ustream.